# How to combine small and large icon in notification drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

```
Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(ic)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

When I create a notification and give it a small and large icon, the large icon appears at the right side, while the small icon appears at the left.

[image]

I want to make the large icon appear on the left side too, instead of the small icon.

Apps like viber and some others can show the contact's picture on the left, with the small icon showing in the corner.

[image]

How do I get it to show like this?